# how to get distinct results using Projections and Criteria

Tags: hibernate, grails-orm, grails

I am trying to load distinct Parents using Criteria in Grails. The query is as following

**Query:**

```
def criteria = Parent.createCriteria();
        results =  criteria.list(max:params.max, offset:params.offset){
            projections{ groupProperty('id') }
            children{
                books{
                    like('title',"%book")
                    }
                }
            order("id","asc")
        }
```

**Domain Classes**

```
    class Parent {

    String name

    static hasMany = [children:Child]

    static constraints = {
    }
}


class Child {

        String name
        Parent parent

        static belongsTo = [parent:Parent]
        static hasMany =   [books:Book]
        static constraints = {
        }
    }


class Book {

        String title
        Child child

        static belongsTo = [child:Child]
        static constraints = {
        }
    }
```

**Question** : I am unable to get distinct Parent Rows.

**Other adopted Approaches and their results:** I donot know why *groupProperty* is not working. I have tried  *distinct* in projections instead of *groupProperty* and it isnt fruitfull too!. if i use  *criteria.listDistinct* instead of *criteria.list* then i am able to get distinct Parent Rows but earlier approach require to get *totalCount* from extra query for pagination. Therefore i am highly intersted in getting distinct Parent Rows using *criteria.list*

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your end goal?  Are you trying to get a list of the Parents that have Children that have Books that match a specific title?

Comment: actually i want to load all parents, unique, those have children with books having title '%M%'.and there problem is groupproperty. Results do not contain distinct parents. If it is difficult to understand query then replace aforementioned query par with following                                                                "  children{
                children{
                    like('name',"pau%")
                    }
                }
            order("id","asc")

Comment: relationships: Parent:Child [1:N] and Child:Book [1:N]

Comment: i assume problem lies in joining. So far i havent  tested it for further reading  http://adhockery.blogspot.com/2009/06/querying-by-association-redux.html

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve the same effect as with `criteria.listDistinct` if you change the criteria query to include distinct root entity results transformer like this:

```
    results =  criteria.list(max:params.max, offset:params.offset){
        children{
            books{
                like('title',"%book")
                }
            }
         resultTransformer Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY            
         order("id","asc")
    }
```

There is however a reason why grails does not return paged results for the listDistinct call so it might be a case to resort to an HQL query with the `in` operator

Comment: Thanks for `resultTransformer Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY`, previously if had 5 entries in hasMany table, my query used to return 5 copies of the parent, after adding this it returns only one as expected.