# Problem with duplicates using Grails' withCriteria function with a many-to-many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, groovy

I've got 2 tables, Question and Answer, with a many-to-many relationship (i.e. Questions can have multiple Answers and Answers can be reused by multiple Questions). For normalization, I have a cross-reference table between them named Question_Answer that has a many-to-one relationship with both tables. These are their class definitions:

```
class Question {
    int id
    int text

    static hasMany = [questionAnswers : QuestionAnswer]
}

class Answer {
    int id
    int text

    static hasMany = [questionAnswers : QuestionAnswer]
}

class QuestionAnswer {
    int id
    Question question
    Answer answer
}
```

I'm trying to get a list of Answers based on certain criteria. Here is my criteria query (using Grails' `withCriteria` function):

```
def listing = Answer.withCriteria {
    cache false
    order "id", "asc"

    eq("id", myAnswerID)

    questionAnswers {
        question {
            isNotNull("text")
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example of the problem I'm having:

I have an Answer that matches 3 different Questions. What I want in the "listing" is 1 `Answer` object, with its `questionAnswers` list populated with the 3 matching `QuestionAnswer` objects. Instead, I'm getting 3 identical `Answer` objects, all with their `questionAnswers` lists populated.

Is there a simple way to achieve what I want? I'm hoping I'm just missing something small.

Any help/suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks,
B.J.

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592042/how-to-get-distinct-results-using-projections-and-criteria

Comment: fyi - there's no need to declare "int id" in domain classes - Grails adds the `id` and `version` fields for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding this to your query to tell the Criteria to return only distinct Answer objects:

```
resultTransformer org.hibernate.Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY
```

Comment: Yes, that seems to have done the trick. I do have a quick follow-up question, though: When I combine the Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY and set the maxResults property, the maxResults is applied to the total count, before the result is transformed. Is there a way to specify a maxResults AFTER transforming the result? Thanks

Comment: I think that DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY is a Hibernate transformation that occurs after the SQL query is run and prevents any duplicates.  Which means there isn't an easy way to get maxResults to run after DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY, as maxResults is a part of the SQL statement.