# Correct pagination withCriteria while looking at many-to-one table (Grails)

Tags: grails, grails-orm

There is a paginated search for `Product` table. The search looks at `Product` objects and also at `ProductParam` objects.

The problem is there are duplicate Products in search result: having 25 items per page, two thirds are duplicated Products.

If applying [resultTransformer org.hibernate.Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181470/problem-with-duplicates-using-grails-withcriteria-function-with-a-many-to-many) in criteria builder, the resulted items per page are fewer than 25 - it's about 6.

In both cases, the search is broken. Could that issue be solved? (Without rewriting the code completely.)

```
class Product {
  String name
  static hasMany = [ params: ProductParam ]
}

class ProductParam {
  String key
  String value
  static belongsTo = [ product: Product ]
}

HibernateCriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = Product.createCriteria()
PagedResultList results = criteriaBuilder.list(max: 25, offset: offset) {
  or {
    // searching in Product
    ilike 'name', "%${query}%"

    // searching in ProductParam
    createAlias('params', 'pp')
    ilike 'pp.value', "%${query}%"
  }
  //resultTransformer org.hibernate.Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY
}
```

Grails 2.2.0, Postgres

Comment: How many in total (ignoring pagination) are you expecting if the query works as expected?

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks a bit overcomplicated :) 
I'd put it like that:

```
def results = Product.withCriteria{
  projections{ distinct 'id' }
  or{
    eq 'name', "%${query}%" // do you really mean *eq* here, not *ilike*?
    params{
      ilike 'value', "%${query}%"
    }
  }
  maxResults 25
  firstResult offset
}
```